# Rendering probleme while rendering the data fetched from the backend in a component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a problem with the re-rendering error!

```
import React , {useEffect} from 'react'
import "./UsernameStory.css";
import Axios from "axios";
import Storyfeed from '../storySmall/Storyfeed';




const UsernameStory = ({match}) => {

    const [statue , setStatue] = React.useState("");
    const [storie , setStorie] = React.useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const urls = match.params.username;
        Axios.post("http://localhost:8080/user/"+urls, {})
            .then((response) => {
                if(response.data.statue)
                {
                    setStatue(response.data.statue);
                }
                if(response.data){
                    setStorie(storie.concat(response.data));
                }
            });
    }, []); // An empty denpendency array allows you to fetch the data once on mount


    return (
        <div>
            <p>{statue}</p>
            {storie.map((story , key) => (<Storyfeed key = {key}  story = {story}/>))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default UsernameStory
```

**Storyfeed.js**

```
import React , {useEffect}from 'react'
import Axios from "axios";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import NotFound from '../../errors/404/NotFound';
import ThumbUpIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ThumbUp';

const Storyfeed = ({story}) => {
    const [votes , setVotes] = React.useState(story.vote);
    const [link , setLink] = React.useState("");

        setLink(story.link)
        let url = `/story/${link}`;
        return(
            <div className = "story">
                <p>{story.username}</p>
                <Link to={url}><p>{story.title}</p></Link>
                <div className = "votes">
                    <ThumbUpIcon />
                    <p> Total Votes : {votes}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
}
```

this is the response

```
response.data = [{
    email: "mouadpro3@gmail.com",
    id: 7,
    link: "hello-world",
    story: "test",
    title: "hello world",
    username: "MH15O",
    votes: 0
},
...
```

I have just fetched some data from my backend and used a `useState` to store the result array which is going to be mapped in order to show some each story data with the **Storyfeed** component
this is the response too , it gives an array of objects, and i wanna map them so that i can show them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're trying not to disturb the previous value of the state by attempting a concat on the previous state value. Try the below

```
response.data = [{
    email: "mouadpro3@gmail.com",
    id: 7,
    link: "hello-world",
    story: "test",
    title: "hello world",
    username: "MH15O",
    votes: 0
},
{...},
{...}];
```

For this response given by you, I've updated the answer

```
const UsernameStory = ({match}) => {

    const [statue, setStatue] = React.useState("");
   
    const [story, setStory] = React.useState([]);

   
   const setMyStory = (sto) => setStory([...story, sto]);
   
   or
 
   const setMyStory = (sto) => setStory(prevState => [...prevState, sto]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const urls = match.params.username;
        Axios.post("http://localhost:8080/user/"+urls, {})
            .then((response) => {
                if( response.data && response.data[0].statue){
                  setStatue(response.data[0].statue);
               } else if(response.data && response.data[0].story) {
                   setMyStory(response.data[0])
                }
            });
    }, []); 


    return (
        <div>
            <p>{statue}</p>
            {story.map((story , key) => (<Storyfeed key = {key}  story = {story}/>))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default UsernameStory
```

Comment: Same rerendering problem :(

Comment: you console.log() the response from the api and paste above to your question.

Comment: email: "mouadpro3@gmail.com"
id: 7
link: "hello-world"
story: "test"
title: "hello world"
username: "MH15O"
votes: 0                               this is in the response.data[0]

Comment: I could only see "story" what about the statue? It's not in the response.

Comment: the statue shows up when the user is not found otherwise the useState stays empty , so eather it will show the statue or it will show  Story published data

Comment: I think i figured out what wrong , the setState in the SetMyStory only takes a value , so the array story is reset to a single element

Comment: the story is the whole thing , meaning that it will render the username and the title of every sing story fetched from the backend

Comment: No the setMyStory method will not reset the array story. Thats why we use ...prevState. We retain what was previously there and update what needs to be updated. Are you still having issues? I thought its resolved and you accepted the solution. So whats the status now?

Comment: i firstly accepted because i thought it worked but not really , do you have a discord or something for more flexibility

Comment: You gave a response structure and stated its in response.data[0] right? I don;t have discord. Would you be able to put your project in codesandbox for me to check?

Comment: yes give me 5min the time to put it there

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/live/e8001eae7f6 here is the codesandbox

Comment: Thanks for your help althought really apreciate it @deechris27

Comment: @MH15O glad to see the issue is resolved :)

Comment: Yeah i managed to solve it , thanks for your help bro !